# new AjaxUpload accept only image from button tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajax-upload

I have here a button with an onload script.

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn default-btn logo_btn" id="photo_uploader">Upload New Photo</button>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function(){
var btnUpload=$('#photo_uploader');
new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
    action: base_URL+'upload',
    data: {pid:$('#page').data('id') },
    dataType: 'json',
    name: 'fileToUpload',
    onSubmit: function(file, ext){
        console.log('onSubmit triggred');
        console.log(ext);
        xr_load(['#logo_btns',"start"]);
         if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))){
             alert ('images only');
        }
    }
});
```

Upon selection, I can see all the filetypes. What I want is to see image file types only automatically like using input file with accept attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best if you use the following

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

all the modern browser supports this.

Comment: the reason i dont use input type file is the design. its better to design button tag

Comment: Then hide the input with css...and then use a button to generate click on the input with javascript.....

Comment: So there will be no solution for this one?

Comment: Of course there is....as I mentioned above, hide the input and on the button set the onclick to ("input[type='file']").focus(); or you can also use click();

Comment: After that you can use ("input[type='file']").change(function(){....get the value and upload the file....});